# Create dynamic tags with Styled Components

Tags: javascript, typescript, styled-components

Is there a way to create a dynamic tag using styled-components?
For example:

```
const MyComponent = styled(CustomTag)``;

<MyComponent element="h1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `as` prop by default on components created with styled-components. If in your example `CustomTag` is also a styled-component that styles a native element (e.g.:)

```
const CustomTag = styled.h1`
  color: red;
`;
```

then you can do

```
const MyComponent = styled(CustomTag)`
  font-size: 64px;
`;

<MyComponent as="span">Something</MyComponent>
```

and you'll end up with a `<span>` tag with `font-size` of 64px and red text color. Of course you can also use `as` prop on `CustomTag` so you don't necessarily need `MyComponent`.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this will help you:

Add you code in your typescript

```
class Test extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `<h1>Hello World...</h1>`;
        this.style.color = "red";
    }
}

customElements.define('test', Test);
```

after compiling refer the js file in you HTML and you can use it like `<test></test>`

Comment: This has nothing to do with styled-components.